# Can you survive a 'fatal' car crash?

Tags: meaning, usage

A headline on [www.bbc.com](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-india-42971500)

> India PM's wife survives fatal car crash

Is 'survives fatal car crash' correct usage?

As per [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fatal) one of the meanings of fatal is 'causing death'.

> **4** a : causing death • a *fatal* crash • a *fatal* disease • a *fatal* wound

This meaning appears to be relevant in this headline.

Comment: It means that the crash was fatal, probably for other people in the car, or in other cars involved,  but luckily she survived, and actually: "*One of her relatives died when their vehicle collided with a truck in the western state of Rajasthan.

Ms Jashodaben, her bodyguard and the driver suffered minor injuries. Seven people were travelling in the SUV.*" http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-india-42971500

Comment: The report says "The vehicle Jashodaben was in collided with a truck on a national highway, killing one passsenger."

Answer (score 2):

The article - presumably http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-asia-india-42971500 - says

> **India PM Narendra Modi's wife survives fatal car crash**
>
> Indian prime minister Narendra Modi's estranged wife, Jashodaben, survived a fatal crash on Wednesday on a national highway, police confirmed to the BBC.
>
> One of her relatives died when their vehicle collided with a truck in the western state of Rajasthan.
>
> Ms Jashodaben, her bodyguard and the driver suffered minor injuries. Seven people were travelling in the SUV.

So somebody died ("One of her relatives"), making this a *fatal* car crash, but Ms Jashodaben did not